# Sorting numbers using struts display tag?

Tags: java, tags, struts

Is it possible? how is it implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Late response, but don't forget to pass any number-like datatype to the view. A string will be sorted as a String, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `displaytag` sorts with full list. Which is basically client-side sort. Where you hand over the full list to `displaytag` to display. You just need to set the property i.e. `<display:column property="amount" sortable="true" sortName="amount" />`.

For the server-side/partial-list sorting, please refer to [external sorting](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html).